# What does the phrase ''extended to'' mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

In this following context, what does the verb phrase ''extend to'' mean?

Should I take the meaning as:
''To include or encompass someone or something''
(The free dictionary.com: extend to)

Is the phrase ''extended to'' adverbial phrase? or adjectival phrase?

Would you let me know your paraphrasing of this parenthesis phrase.

The context:

> The Buddhist doctrine of rebirth — which is really the same as the law of causality **extended to** the mental and moral domain — has nothing  whatever to do with the brahman doctrine of reincarnation, or  transmigration.

Source: Page. 8
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Answer (score 1):

These are all translations. That said:

To extend something to something means: to make is apply to something.

**extended to the mental and moral domain** is a past participle phrase used as an adjective to describe the "law of causality".

Comment: Would you give a simple type of this sentence? @Lambie.  Thanks.

Comment: as applied to the mental and moral domain